# bindRows on a SAPUI5 Table

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a JSON-View which creates a Table

```
{
  "Type": "sap.ui.core.mvc.JSONView",
  "content": [
    {
      "Type": "sap.ui.table.Table",
      "id": "operationTable",
      "columns": [
        {
          "Type": "sap.ui.table.Column",
          "label": "Operation Name",
          "template": {
            "Type": "sap.ui.commons.TextView",
            "text": "{name}"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I am trying to bind Rows to the Table with a JSON-Model:

```
{
  binding: {
    operationX: 
    {
      name: "First Object"
    },
    operationY: {
      name: "Second Object"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to bind Operation Names to Tablerows. This is how i try to achieve my goal:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(jsonModel);  //The Json-Model one code block above

var oTable = oView.byId("operationTable");
oTable.setModel(oModel);
oTable.bindRows("/binding/"); //This is the problem
```

The problem is that **binding** isn't an Array of objects, but a Object with Objects. I can't access a specific KEY-VALUE-Pair like I would do when I would write

```
oTable.bindRows("/binding/operationX");
```

The Second Part of **/binding/**{secondPart} has to be changeable.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

List bindings require an Array as underlying data structure (at least in version 1.26 which I have to use). Try this [example](http://jsbin.com/kayoca/1/edit?html,console,output).

Comment: seems to work with javascript. how can i use bindProperty in my JSON-View?

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems like you can't bind this JSON:

```
{
  binding: {
    operationX: 
    {
      name: "First Object"
    },
    operationY: {
      name: "Second Object"
    }
  }
}
```

So you have to parse it to a JSON-Array like that:

```
function parseToArray(obj){
    var myArray = new Array();

    for(var key in obj){
        myArray.push(obj[key]);
    }

    return myArray;
}
```

Unfortunately, you can't bind a **sap.ui.core.ListItem** to a Table like you can do it with a [DropDownBox](http://jsbin.com/laqoyoduca/1/edit?html,output)